# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I upgraded from spring 2 to spring 3 and from java 8 to java 17. Now I have this error message:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Parameter 2 of function extract() has type TEMPORAL, but argument is of type java.time.Duration

I don't know if this method is causing this:

```
public static Query updateSchedulerControl(EntityManager em, String query, String podId) { 
    Query q = em.createQuery(query);    
    q.setParameter("podId", podId);     
    q.setParameter("sysDate", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now())); 
      return q; 
}
```

How do I resolve this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: It was an “extract” that was in a sql that used this method.

Answer (score 0):

It was an “extract” that was in a sql that used this method.